# Summarise active users by date range - Symonfy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating a basic app using Symfony 6 and Doctrine. What I want to be able to do is summarise the number of active users, over time.

I am using vanilla JS to query the server every 30 seconds. When the user loads the page, they get assigned a uniqid() from PHP, which JS uses to update the server. When the server is updated, it finds the uniqid in the DB (or creates a new row if it doesn't exist yet). The database records the time when the uniqid was created, and then updates another datetime field, the idea being that when the user closes the page, I have a start time and an end time.

Finally, I want to be able to download the results (I am filtering a date range in Doctrine which is fine), and so what I want to end up with is a summary of the activity. SO rather than downloading all of the uniqids and the start and end time, I want to have a time column, and next to each time increment (which I think will be 15 minutes) I will have a summary of every uniqid that was active at that point.

So far, I have a form behind a Symfony firewall that allows me to filter the databse by date and download a CSV table of the database, and I've used Excel to create a pivot table to get the resutls I want, but I'm thinking I must be able to do this in PHP.

I'm hoping this hasn't been answered already, but I can't even think what to search in order to best find what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but stackoverflow isn't a chatgpt prompt. It's usually like ... "I have done this [code snippet] and my database looks like this [sqlfiddle] and my queries are these, but it outputs this [example data] instead of this [target example data] and I don't know how." Show us concrete effort, because so far, it's all very abstract and unspecific. Good luck though.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! I don’t know why but ChatGPT had completely gone from my mind!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.